# How to rebuild nexus repository metadata using REST API?

Tags: rest, metadata, nexus

I found out in the nexus REST API the /service/local/metadata/{domain}/{target}/content.

But when I try to execute it (for example with curl)

```
curl -v --request DELETE  --user "login:password"  --silent http://nexusHost/local/metadata/repositories/myRepository/content
```

I got a this message back and the work is not done

```
HTTP/1.1 405 La m�thode HTTP DELETE n''est pas support�e par cette URL
```

Can you help me make this work ? thanks.

Note: using Nexus 2.11.3-01

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just mispell you request! (you forgot to add **service/** before local.

```
curl -v --request DELETE  --user "login:password"  --silent http://nexusHost/service/local/metadata/repositories/myRepository/content
```